# Symfony2: How to use INSERT DELAYED with doctrine or create a non-blocking database operation?

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony, doctrine

For performance reasons I would like to persist a log object using mysql's INSERT DELAYED query.

Do you have any ideas how that could be performed using doctrine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why you probably shouldn't use INSERT DELAYED:

> As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and will be removed
>   in a future release. Use INSERT (without DELAYED) instead.

([official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-delayed.html))

### The symfony2 solution:

With symfony2 you can perform a non-blocking database-operation by creating a listener/subscriber for the `kernel.terminate` event and executing it in there.

This event is fired **after** the response has been sent. It's being used by monolog in the production environment for example.

Create a listener class first:

```
namespace Acme\Your;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent;

class LongOperationLogger
{
    protected $om;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function onKernelTerminate(KernelEvent $event)
    {
        // don't do anything if there is not data
        if ( null !== $this->data ) {
            return;
        }

        $logEntry = new LogEntry('I will not block the response.', $this->data);

        $this->om->persist($logEntry);
        $this->om->flush();
    }
}
```

Then define it as a service and inject your object-manager:

```
# app/config/config.yml

services:
    long_operation.logger:
        class: Acme\Your\LongOperationLogger
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate }
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

Finally, you can add data to the logger from inside a controller or some service which in turn activates and executes the database-operation in a non-blocking way *after* the response has been sent.

```
public function someAction()
{
    // some condition
    // if (...) {
    //     ...
    // }

    $this->get('long_operation.logger')->setData($whatever)
}
```

Comment: thank you. I've just implemented your solution and my login request is now significantly faster.